# Copy assignment operator with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, assignment-operator

My copy constructor below works fine, but I don't understand what is wrong with my copy assignment operator.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts> class foo;

template <typename Last>
class foo<Last> {
    Last last;
public:
    foo (Last r) : last(r) { }
    foo() = default;
    foo (const foo& other) : last(other.last) { }

    foo& operator= (const foo& other) {
        last = other.last;
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
class foo<First, Rest...> : public foo<Rest...> {
    First first;
public:
    foo (First f, Rest... rest) : foo<Rest...>(rest...), first(f) { }
    foo() = default;
    foo (const foo& other) : foo<Rest...>(other), first(other.first) { std::cout << "[Copy constructor called]\n"; }

    foo& operator= (const foo& other) {  // Copy assignment operator
        if (&other == this)
            return *this;
        first = other.first;
        return foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
    }
};

int main() {
    const foo<int, char, bool> a(4, 'c', true);
    foo<int, char, bool> b = a;  // Copy constructor works fine.
    foo<int, char, bool> c;
//  c = a;  // Won't compile.
}
```

Error message:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'foo<int, char, bool>&' from expression of type 'foo<char, bool>'
         return foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
                                              ^
```

Can someone point out the problem here?

Comment: Why don't you use copy-and-swap? Do you expect `T`s that aren't swappable, or measurable performance problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your return statement

```
return foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
```

Returns a `foo<Rest...>` (that's the type of reference `operator=` is defined with). But it does so from an operator that is supposed to return a `foo<First, Rest...>&`.

Essentially, you return a `Base` where a `Derived&` reference is expected. The reference simply won't bind.

Fortunatly the fix is easy: don't return the result of `foo<Rest...>::operator=`, return `*this` instead.

```
foo& operator= (const foo& other) {  // Copy assignment operator
    if (&other == this)
        return *this;
    first = other.first;
    foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @ Story Teller   Yes, indeed.  As a bonus, the `if (&other == this) return *this;` is being called multiple times, but redundantly, right (it need only be called once)?  But no way to avoid this?

Comment: @prestokeys - You can always have `operator=` delegate to another named member that doesn't check (and is implemented recursively).

Comment: @ StoryTeller    Answer accepted, and I implemented your idea to optimize it in a separate answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @prestokeys You probably don't actually want to implement anything recursively. Use pack expansion instead. Can save a lot of template bloat in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like return from `operator=` in the derived class is incorrect:

```
return foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
```

It returns base class, while it should be `*this`. Change it to

```
this -> foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
return *this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to StoryTeller, here is an optimized fully compiling solution (operator= delegated to another named member name `copy_data` that doesn't check for self-assignment, and is implemented recursively):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts> class foo;

template <typename Last>
class foo<Last> {
    Last last;
public:
    foo (Last r) : last(r) { }
    foo() = default;
    foo (const foo& other) : last(other.last) { }

    foo& operator= (const foo& other) {
        if (&other == this)
            return *this;
        last = other.last;
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    void copy_data (const foo& other) {
        last = other.last;
    }
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
class foo<First, Rest...> : public foo<Rest...> {
    First first;
public:
    foo (First f, Rest... rest) : foo<Rest...>(rest...), first(f) { }
    foo() = default;
    foo (const foo& other) : foo<Rest...>(other), first(other.first) { std::cout << "[Copy constructor called]\n"; }

    foo& operator= (const foo& other) {  // Copy assignment operator
        if (&other == this)
            return *this;
        first = other.first;
//      foo<Rest...>::operator= (other);
        foo<Rest...>::copy_data(other);
        std::cout << "[Assignment operator called]\n";
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    void copy_data (const foo& other) {
        first = other.first;
        foo<Rest...>::copy_data(other);
    }
};

int main() {
    const foo<int, char, bool> a(4, 'c', true);
    foo<int, char, bool> b = a;  // Copy constructor works fine.
    foo<int, char, bool> c;
    c = b;  // Copy assignment operator works fine (and optimized).
}
```